# Python use sys.argv in a function to read a filename

Tags: python, argv, sys

I have a function that takes in and reads a csv file such that when i can type

`python myscript.py filename.csv` to run my script. Below is my function :

```
def read(sys.argv[1]):
 ...
 ...
```

However i get this error:

```
  File "myscript.py", line 6
    def read(sys.argv[1]):
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can i re write my script to be able to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass `sys.argv[1]` as an argument to `read` when you *call* it, not when you *define* it:

```
def read(argument): # define it with argument
    print argument  # do whatever with "argument"

read(sys.argv[1])   # call it here
```